# Include hidden files in snap

Tags: snap

I'm trying to create a snap package from a folder structure using the "copy" plugin.  When I do this, hidden files in the folder structure do not get included, but I need them to.

Is there any options to tell the copy plugin to include hidden files?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. `snapcraft help copy` knows more about the subject:

```
- files:
  (object)
  A dictionary of key-value pairs. The key is the current location of the
  file relative to snapcraft.yaml (unless `source` is specified, in which
  case it's relative to the root of the source). The value is where to
  place the file in-snap, and is relative to the root of the snap. This
  works like `cp -r <key> <value>`. Note that globbing is supported for the
  key, allowing one to use *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [].
```

Using `snapcraft init`, I put together a very quick project for this:

```
daniel@daydream:~/test$ touch bla .bla blubb .blubb
daniel@daydream:~/test$ find
.
./blubb
./.bla
./bla
./snapcraft.yaml
./.blubb
daniel@daydream:~/test$
```

The `snapcraft.yaml` file looks like this:

```
name: my-snap
version: 0
summary: This is my-snap's summary
description: This is my-snap's description
confinement: devmode

parts:
    my-part:
        plugin: copy
        files:
          "*": contents/
          ".*": contents/
```

After running `snapcraft`, I can see the following files in the package:

```
daniel@daydream:~/test$ find prime/
prime/
prime/meta
prime/meta/snap.yaml
prime/contents
prime/contents/blubb
prime/contents/.bla
prime/contents/bla
prime/contents/.blubb
daniel@daydream:~/test$
```